# How are search keywords saved?

Tags: xdb, content-search, reporting

I'm using `Sitecore 9 update 1`, I'm trying to get the top trending search keywords by users for my website.

I discovered that the local search keywords are stored at table `DimensionKeys` in the **Reporting** database, and its count in table `Fact_SearchMetrics`.

It seems the keywords are stored after 25 minutes. Not all keywords are stored it seems. I have been unable to find any documentation for this in the xConnect Documentation.

How can I access this data to extract trending search keywords?

Answer (score 2):

The keywords are stored in the `WebVisit` facet https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-platform/en/add-interaction-events.html:

```
var webVisitFacet = new WebVisit();

// Populate data about the web visit
webVisitFacet.Browser = new BrowserData() { BrowserMajorName = "Chrome", BrowserMinorName = "Desktop", BrowserVersion = "22.0" };
webVisitFacet.Language = "en";
webVisitFacet.OperatingSystem = new OperatingSystemData() { Name = "Windows", MajorVersion = "10", MinorVersion = "4" };
webVisitFacet.Referrer = "www.google.com";
webVisitFacet.Screen = new ScreenData() { ScreenHeight = 1080, ScreenWidth = 685 };
webVisitFacet.SearchKeywords = "sitecore";
webVisitFacet.SiteName = "website";
```

Comment: I want to understand its behavior, what is the pattern it uses to save the search keywords, as the it's stored automatically with out writing any code.

Comment: The Tracker saves the keywords to xConnect and they are aggregated then to the Reporting database. Here's how the keywords are parsed from URL: https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecorejohn_blog/posts/identifying-search-engines-and-search-terms-with-the-sitecore-customer-engagement-platform, see also `ParseGenericSearchEngine` in `parseReferrer` pipeline.